# How to fetch all images from cloudinary folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cloudinary

I want to fetch all the images from a folder in cloudinary.
as per the below code i want to return all the data fetched as a response  to get post controller but when i make request from my react app it says result is not defined.
Please share some logic on how to return all the fetched images

Also need help on how to fetch a single image inside a folder in cloudinary using {id} as param

```
`    




     import { catchAsyncErr } from "../middleware/catchAsyncErrors.js";
     export const getPosts = catchAsyncErr(async (req, res) => {
     cloudinary.v2.api.resources({
     type: 'upload',
     prefix: '{my_folder_name}' // add your folder
   },
    function(error, result) { console.log(result, error) });
    res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    result,
   });
  });
   //
   router.route("/posts").get(getPosts)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    result,
      });
```

inside

```
function(error, result) { console.log(result, error);
res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        result,
       });
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your environment as follows:

```js
import {v2 as cloudinary} from 'cloudinary';
          
cloudinary.config({ 
  /* Your options goes here */
});

export default cloudinary;
```

Then use this code that filters the folder you want to access.

```js
const data = await cloudinary.search
      .expression('folder=<folder name>')
      .execute()
    
res.status(200).json(data)
```

That code gives you a general object, but if you only want the specific part for the files use this instead:

```js
const { resources } = await cloudinary.search
      .expression('folder=<folder name>')
      .execute()
    
res.status(200).json(resources)
```

This returns an array of objects, so you can iterate over it.

This is an example I made:

```js
const {resources} = await cloudinary.search
      .expression('folder=csv')
      .execute()
    
    resources.map(async file =>{
      await fetch(file.secure_url)
        .then(response =>{
          if (!response.ok) {
            return res.status(400).json(response.statusText)
          }
          response.text()
            .then(data =>{
              console.log(data)
            })
        })
    })
```

I hope this was helpful.